# Why does VS Code display a working function as "undeclared name"?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I made a very simple Go program, showing the current time. The function gets loaded from another source file with the same package (main).

For some reason, VS Code thinks, the function has an undeclared name.

Here's the code:

main.go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World!")
    displayTime()
    fmt.Scanf("h")
}
```

show_time.go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func displayTime() {
    fmt.Println(time.Now())
}
```

It's in the same directory, and everything compiles right. It's just that red mark that won't go and would disturb me. Also, the red number gets added by 1, everytime I call a extern function..

Comment: Are you using `gopls`?

Comment: @Zyl What is that?

Comment: If you don't have `go.mod` setup, create one and open vscode from the directory where `go.mod` file is. Need to teach the language server (gopls) that these two files are in the same module.